# React: How to update an item in array without removing all the other props?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a handler that would change the background color of all the components defined in the state. 
in the state I define usedComponents which is an array of objects that each represent the list of properties of an individual component (backgroundColor, fontSize etc).

My state looks like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    components: components,
    usedComponents: [components[0], components[1], components[2]],
  };
  this.changeComponentsBgColorHandler = this.changeComponentsBgColorHandler.bind(
    this
  );
}
```

components is imported array of all the components and usedComponents is a list of currently active components.
example of a component object:

```
{
  componentName: "Header 02",
  padding: "small",
  fontSize: "small",
  fontColor: "#1f1f1f",
  fontFamily: "Sans-serif",
  backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
  image: placeholderLogo,
  selected: false,
  isEditing: false,
  margins: false,
  roundCorners: "none",
  mobile: "false"
}
```

To change the backgroundColor property I created a handler:

```
changeComponentsBgColorHandler = color => {
  this.setState(state => {
    const usedComponents = state.usedComponents.map(     
      item => (item.backgroundColor = color)
    );

    return {
      usedComponents
    };
  });
};
```

The problem I have is that this removes all the other properties from every individual object and sets only the backgroundColor for each. How do I update only the backgroundColor prop without removing all the other props from an updated object?

Comment: Can you show your state?

Comment: I updated my question to show the state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that you don't return the same object from the `map` function, you just `return` the updated color so you basically end up with `['blue', 'blue', ...]`.

You need to [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) all the properties to the new object and then change the `backgroundColor`.

```
changeComponentsBgColorHandler = color => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    usedComponents: prevState.usedComponents.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      backgroundColor: color,
    })),
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried spreading the item before but I forgot to put the curly brackets. :) I accepted your answer because it's more compact than the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

Do like this

```
changeComponentsBgColorHandler = color => {
    this.setState(state => {
        const usedComponents = state.usedComponents.map(     
            item => ({...item, backgroundColor: color})
        );

        return {
            usedComponents
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I tried spreading the item before but I forgot to put the curly brackets. :)